# How to Clear multiple dropdowns at a time using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

In my application, i have 5 dropdown lists.

When one dropdown is selected, i need to reset all the other four dropdowns.

I am assigning the class clear to all dropdown lists.

I am trying to do like this:

```
    $("#ddl1").change(function()
    {
      $(this).removeClass("clear");
      $(.clear).each(function()
{
    $(this).val('');
});
    });
```

But, the above snippet is working. I mean its not clearing other dropdown's

Please suggest..

Comment: `$('.clear')` instead of `$(.clear)`. Why not just `$('.clear').val('');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the class selector should have quotes  `$('.clear')` and btw
you don't need a clear class also

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('select').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out some quotes in your class selector. Should be:

```
   $(".clear").each(function() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8U49M/)***

You don't need to clear the class `clear`, use `not(this)` to exclude the selected dropdown box.

```
$("#ddl1").change(function () {
    $('.clear').not(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to do this would be to change the selected property of the `<option>` tags:

```
$('#ddl1').on('change', function()
{
    // un-select the selected dropdown item
    $('.clear option:selected').prop('selected', false);

    // select only first dropdown item
    $('.clear option').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});
```